# Form labels need for attribute

Tags: bug, design

The `label` elements for tags and edit comment in the forms for editing posts and asking questions need the `for` attribute, linking them to their respective `input` fields. The label for question title appears to have it, but the other two do not. This is useful for accessibility, especially since the tag label doesn't exist next to the `input` field anymore in the HTML.